# How to iterate over a multiline string with perl's regex

Tags: regex, perl

I need to extract several sections from a multiline string with Perl. I'm applying the same regex in a while loop.
My problem is to get the last section which ends with the file. My workaround is to append the marker. This way the regex will always find and end.
Is there a better way to do it?

Example file:

```
Header

==== /home/src/file1.c#1 ====
content file1
line 1 of file1
line 2 of file1
line 3 of file1

another line of file1

==== /home/src/file2.c#1 ====
content file2
line 1 of file2
line 2 of file2
line 3 of file2

another line of file2
```

Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my $desc = do { local $/ = undef; <> };

$desc .= "\n===="; # set the end marker

while($desc =~ /^==== (?<filename>.*?)#.*?====$(?<content>.*?)(?=^====)/mgsp) {
  print "filename=", $+{filename}, "\n";
  print "content=", $+{content}, "\n";
}
```

This way the script finds both segments. How can I avoid adding the marker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use of the greediness modifier `?` is a giant red flag. You can usually get away with using it once in a pattern, but more than that is usually a bug. If you want to match text that doesn't contain a string, use the following instead:

```
(?:(?!STRING).)*
```

So that gets you the following:

```
/
   ^==== [ ] (?<filename> [^\n]+ ) [ ] ====\n
   (?<content> (?:(?! ^==== ).)* )
/xsmg
```

---

Code:

```
my $desc = do { local $/; <DATA> };

while (
   $desc =~ /
      ^==== [ ] (?<filename> [^\n]+ ) [ ] ====\n
      (?<content> (?:(?! ^==== ).)* )
   /xsmg
) {
   print "filename=<<$+{filename}>>\n";
   print "content=<<$+{content}>>\n";
}

__DATA__
Header

==== /home/src/file1.c#1 ====
content file1
line 1 of file1
line 2 of file1
line 3 of file1

another line of file1

==== /home/src/file2.c#1 ====
content file2
line 1 of file2
line 2 of file2
line 3 of file2

another line of file2
```

Output:

```
filename=<</home/src/file1.c#1>>
content=<<content file1
line 1 of file1
line 2 of file1
line 3 of file1

another line of file1

>>
filename=<</home/src/file2.c#1>>
content=<<content file2
line 1 of file2
line 2 of file2
line 3 of file2

another line of file2
>>
```

Comment: you use the `[ ]` because that's the way to put a space into an extended regex?

Comment: You could use `\ `, but I find `[ ]` more readable. Two other options: `\x20`, `\N{SPACE}`

Comment: I see. I'm trying to understand this expression `^====(?<content>(?:(?!^====).)*)`. I understand it catches everything behind `^====` which doesn't contain `^====`. The `?:` avoids catching the expression in the parens. I don't get the `).)*` construct.

Comment: `).)*` it not a valid regex pattern. I already explained what `(?:(?!PAT).)*)` does. It's simply `(?! ^==== ).` inside of `(?: ... )*`. Do you understand each  of those? A bunch of (`(?: ... )*`) characters that aren't the start of `^====` (`(?! ^==== ).`).

Comment: yeah, I got this later that night. thanks for explaining it again though.

Answer (score 1):

You've made this more awkward by slurping the whole file in the first place. This is relatively simple if you read the file line-by-line

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $file;

while ( <> ) {
    if ( /^====\s+(.*\S)#\S*\s+====/ ) {
        $file = $1;
        print "filename=$file\n";
        print 'content=';
    }
    elsif ( $file ) {
        print;
    }
}
```

#### output

```
filename=/home/src/file1.c
content=content file1
line 1 of file1
line 2 of file1
line 3 of file1

another line of file1

filename=/home/src/file2.c
content=content file2
line 1 of file2
line 2 of file2
line 3 of file2

another line of file2
```

Alternatively, if you need to store the whole content per file, perhaps as a hash, it would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $file;
my %data;

while ( <> ) {
    if ( /^====\s+(.*\S)#\S*\s+====/ ) {
        $file = $1;
    }
    elsif ( $file ) {
        $data{$file} .= $_;
    }
}

for my $file ( sort keys %data ) {
    print "filename=$file\n";
    print "content=$data{$file}";
}
```

The output is identical to that of the first version above

Comment: I found a way on which I felt comfortable to solve my problem. To me this solution here looks more complicated. My example was only the core of my script. I subsequently analyze each content and need it in a string variable to hand it to a sub. I also need the list of files + additional information in that line which was omitted from my original question to keep it simple. Remember perl's motto: TIMTOWTDI.

Comment: @SteffenRoller: Your original approach was clearly *too complicated* because you needed help with it! It is common to try to make regular expressions do too much: there is often a more appropriate tool in the language. If you have a better solution then you should show it here as another answer. Please remember that your question's primary purpose is to help others with a similar issue. You should also think about opening a scalar variable for input, with `open my $fh, '<', \$var`. And the first `T` in *TMTOWTDI* is *"There's"*, so there's no `I` :)

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion. My very last comment to this subject: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThereIsMoreThanOneWayToDoIt, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it, http://perl.wikia.com/wiki/TIMTOWTDI. It's on the Internet so it must be true :-).